# get only part of string using preg_match

Tags: php, string, preg-match, substring

I have an array named

```
$array_fields = array(
'field_0_0_4_target_range',
'field_0_0_5_target_range_criteria', 
'field_0_0_6_target_range_count');
```

I want to assign it to have an output of

```
$key = array('target_range', 'target_range_criteria', 'target_range_count');
```

I tried this and I get the desired result:

```
foreach($array_fields as $field) {
   if(preg_match('/target_range/', $field)) {
      $key[] = substr($field,12); //hard coded
   }
}
```

The problem with this line of code `"$key[] = substr($field,12)"` is that I may have a field containing `"field_0_0_10_target_range_value"`. 
This will contain an undesirable result `"_target_range_value"`. How can I make sure that I get all fields containing `"target_range_*"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code.

```
$array_fields = array(
'field_0_0_4_target_range',
'field_0_0_5_target_range_criteria', 
'field_0_0_6_target_range_count'
);

$new_fields = array();
foreach ($array_fields as $v){
  if(preg_match('/target_range.*/',$v,$matchs))
  {
     $new_fields[] = $matchs[0];
  }
}

print_r($new_fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Here I just go through each array element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), then I grab everything with `target_range*` and return it)

```
<?php

    $array_fields = [
            'field_0_0_4_target_range',
            'field_0_0_5_target_range_criteria', 
            'field_0_0_6_target_range_count'
        ];

    $array_fields = array_map(function($v){
        preg_match_all("/target_range.*/", $v, $matches);
        return $matches[0][0];
    }, $array_fields);


    print_r($array_fields);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => target_range [1] => target_range_criteria [2] => target_range_count )
```